# Laravel with Maatwebsite returns empty array in v 4.1.30

Tags: php, arrays, excel, laravel

I am using Laravel with Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel.
https://github.com/Maatwebsite

My version of Laravel was v 4.1.28 and uploading excel worked well. When installing another plugin (moltin / laravel cart https://github.com/moltin/laravel-cart) Laravel automatically updated to v 4.1.30

After that the following code stopped working:

```
$excel = Excel::load('uploads/'.$this->fileName)->calculate()->select(array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13))->toArray();
```

and now it's returning an empty array every time. I found a backup from version 4.1.28 and it's still working great without code changes.

Any suggestions what I should do to make it work with v 4.1.30?